# Null value when passing between view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

It's driving me nuts, because it has never happened to me before, and I have done this dozens of times.

Passing a value between two view controllers results in the value being `NULL`.

I have a `prepareForSegue:` method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"LoginSegue"]) {
        UITabBarController *destinationTabController = [segue destinationViewController];
        ViewController *destinationViewController = destinationTabController.selectedViewController;
        NSLog(@"Logged user is %@.", loggedUser); //This prints out the user correctly
        destinationViewController.currentUser = loggedUser;
    }
}
```

But when the segue is performed I try to log the `currentUser` value and it is `NULL`.

Any ideas, folks?

Comment: Try logging `destinationViewController`.

Comment: Yup, I am a fool. It was null. Changing it (for now) to [destinationTabController viewController] objectAtIndex: 0] resolved the issue.

Comment: :) Whenever something doesn't work, log the heck out of it. Objective-C doesn't barf when things are nil, so this can always be the cause. Another terrific reason for switching to Swift: you should consider doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tab bar controller is not in the interface so nothing is selected. Hence `destinationViewController` is `nil` and your attempt to set its `currentUser` does nothing.